# Drupal 7 merging two projects into one, nesting functions problems

Tags: php, drupal

I have a problem with drupal projects. In general there are two drupal installations: one is **foo.com** and other installation in **foo.com/bar**. So there is two admin panels and two databases.

My task is to merge these projects (only one drupal installation and one admin panel).
I have moved all modules from **foo.com/bar/sites/all** into to **foo.com/sites/all** (except one - entity.module). I have created page for **foo.com/new_bar** to act as **foo.com/bar**. Now I'm facing huge problem. When I go to **foo.com/new_bar** without that entity module everything is ok. But **foo.com/bar** needs this module. When I try to add entity.module to project I get error.

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!
When xdebug.max_nesting_level is increased I get 101 response code (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Without entity module I can access admin panel / site, but when I add this module to modules folder I get error.

Comment: if your devel and devel_themer modules are on, try turning them off and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

In your case the best solution would be Drupal Multi-site concept, which means single Drupal code base and multiple databases. You can have n number of sites under "sites" folder.

Refer this for multi-site :

https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

for installation refer below links,

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-windows/

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-linux/